# Arabic script renders incorrectly on Google's developer tools emulator

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

This is more of a question than a problem. We've noticed that some Arabic characters render incorrectly when using Google's Developer Tools to emulate a mobile experience.

Has anyone seen anything similar/have any thoughts as to why this might be?

Funnily enough, when viewing these characters on an actual mobile device, or on desktop version, they look completely fine! It really seems to be just the emulated mobile experience.

Our website is developed using a combination of HTML, CSS, ASP.NET and JS.

The character combinations that are not rendering correctly are:
ا + ل + ا --> It should look like this: الا
ا + ل + م --> It should look like this: الم

In both cases the letters get really closely stuck together and are unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to System.Web in your ASP.NET controller and use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(<yourstring>)
```

This will encode all html characters changing, for example > to > and so on. 
Encoded string will be rendered correctly.